# How to filter django queryset with exclude?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Suppose I have the following models

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):              
        return self.name


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):              
        return self.name


class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

And I have Entry object e

How can I get all blogs that do not contain e?

How can I get all authors that are not associated with e?

How to exclude a queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK first this is how you would get the entry object and exclude e, I'll just assume e is the primary key. Then you can get all the authors except the ones related to e using the ORM, and then you could get all the blogs that have no mention of the e object using a related query which basically flips the foreign key.

```
  exclude_e = Entry.objects.exclude(pk=e)
  get_authors = exclude_e.authors.all()
  get_blogs = exclude_e.blog_set.all()
```

Comment: There is a manytomanyfield in Entry , authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

I want exactly all blogs that do not contain e. not the other way around...

Comment: Can you provide a doc link for exclude_object ?

Comment: Sure https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#exclude, why is something not working?

Comment: I only see .exclude(**kwargs) but there is no exclude_object ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87033/discussion-between-appa-lover-and-brian).